# HyperLinks In DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am working on C# application which is like a small search engine.  The user will enter a word and the program will return the files that contains this word.

I have an array of file paths (as strings) and I want to show these paths as links in a `DataGridView`, so that when the user clicks the file name the file will be opened.

Note: I am working on C# Winforms, not ASP.net

Comment: I'm not aware of a `GridView` in Winforms.  Do you perhaps mean `DataGridView`?

Comment: yes I mean datagridview
sorry I forgot to mention that in the question

Answer (score 4):

I think I have The Answer of my question
I added a DataGridViewLinkColumn to the DataGridView
now the next step will fill the Data into the datagridview
and the File names will appear like links:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] SS = new string[3];
        SS[0] = "C:\\test1.txt";
        SS[1] = "C:\\test2.txt";
        for (int i = 0; i < SS.Length; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(SS[i]);
        }
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```

The Last step :
now I want to open the file when the user click it
I will use the "CellContentClick" event and this code will achieve it:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string filepath= (string)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filepath);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`DataGridViewLinkColumn` looks promising.

- [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewlinkcolumn.aspx) on `DataGridViewLinkColumn`
- [Another page](http://en.csharp-online.net/Presenting_Data_with_the_DataGridView_Control_in_.NET_2.0%E2%80%94DataGridViewLinkColumn) describing `DataGridViewLinkColumn`

Answer (score 0):

Here are several articles covering this for .NET 1.1. The [DataGridViewLinkColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewlinkcolumn.aspx) is in .NET 2.0 and newer.

- http://www.drdobbs.com/database/184416697
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/Datagrid_ColumnStyles.aspx
- http://www.devnewsgroups.net/windowsforms/t14092-linklabel-datagrid-windows-form.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Links can be dynamically added from aspx also using

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
 <HeaderTemplate>
 <a>Eamil Address</a>
 </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:HyperLink id="HyperLink1"
      Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Professor_email") %>'
      NavigateUrl='mailto:<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Professor_email") %>'
      runat="server"/>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <EditItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox
      Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Professor_email") %>' 
      runat="server"/>
      </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>`
```