# Open a link in browser from winforms gridview column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am new to winforms.I cannot post any code as I am using a designer for my gridview in winforms. I have 2 columns. In 1 column links name is there and other column which is hidden has link names actual link. E.g if in column 1 Google is written so, there is 2nd column(hidden) which has http://www.google.com in it. When I click the datagridview cell with links name, the link should open in browser. Is there a way to do it. I googled it but all I got is 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530297/hyperlinks-in-datagridview). Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is to add an `OnClick` handler to your row and from there [start a new process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx) which will launch a browser with the url:

```
private void OnClick(object sender, RowEventArgs e) // I don't know exactly how the event handlers signature is
{
    // Get the url from the row
    var url = e.Row.Columns[1].Value;
    Process.Start(url);
}
```

**EDIT**

The code above will start the default browser. If you want to start a non-default browser i.e. IE (pun intended) you'll have to use an overload of [`Process.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass it the path to executable and the url like this:

```
Process.Start("iexplore.exe", url);
```

Comment: Tanks for the reply. This will open in default browser, right.? Or can we specify browser also.?